# Stacktracing Functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I know I saw a link to a great description of this somewhere, but alas I cannot dig it out again. I am having trouble stacktracing with console.log in Javascript because they are all coming up ambiguous (usually completely unrelated to the actual location of calling the code).

This is, of course, not advantageous.

```
var myObject = Class.extend({
    init: function() {
        Do Stuff Here
    },

    doOtherStuff: function() {
        Incorrect Stuff Here - Throws Error
    }
});

var objInstance = new myObject;
objInstance.doOtherStuff;       // Error!
```

It won't tell me where the error is occuring in the Firebug stacktrace. I know there's a way to fix this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I know I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

EDIT: Added the John Resig Class declaration. Been using them so long, forgot all about prototyping (bad) and just wrote it without. Fixed it so this is the ACTUAL code (thought I was being smart, bypassing putting the Class declaration to prevent confusion...ending up looking stupid)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a wrong usage of new. `myObject` should there be a function. And both methods should be affected to myObject.prototype.init and myObject.prototype.doOtherStuff.

Moreover as far as it's now a class its name should not make think about an object and its first letter should be uppercase.

If you actually did not want to use the new keyword and just clone the object, you will have to find or write a cloning routine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this js oop guideline
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript